# Why are devd rules applied before devfs rules?

Tags: freebsd, devices

### My problem

I have the following lines in `/etc/devd.conf` which execute the `usbhidaction` for a `/dev/uhid*` device with the named vendor and product id.

```
attach 100 {
    match "vendor"  "0x046a";
    match "product" "0x0107";
    action "/usr/local/bin/sudo -u my_user /usr/bin/usbhidaction -f $device-name -p /var/hid_run/usbaction.pid -c /etc/hidactions/cherry_JK0200";
};
```

and the following lines in `/etc/devfs.rules`

```
[tant=10]
add path 'uhid*' mode 0660 group hid
```

But when I reboot the devd part is executed before the devfs part and then `my_user` has no permissions to read from `/dev/uhid*`.

- Now why is devfs slower then devd, and what can I do to fix this?
- Is there another way to configure the devfs?

### Why I do this

I bought a new keyboard and the function keys are an additional usb-hid device.
Now I wanted to execute small scripts when I press one of these function keys, like decrease volume or mute volume.

Since the scripts are from the my_user I don't want the programs be executed by root. Especially not something like a calculator or a shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Devd runs BEFORE rc and therefore before devfs - this was carefully chosen by its creator - you can see his reasoning here: http://www.usenix.org/events/bsdcon03/tech/full_papers/losh/losh.pdf (Chapt. 7.2)

Devd runs entirely in user space, there is no issue with root privileges.

Unless you choose to sudo - which is what you did.

Use devd.conf to set a value in user space. Test for your flag in devfs.

Comment: Ah thanks for explanation! But then it es not possible for me to start `usbhidaction` as a different user?